# Get relation pivot table json laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

i have table1 with columns ['id', 'code', 'year', 'status','anggaran'] and relationship:

```
public function workunit(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Modules\Master\Unit\Model', 'table2', 'table1_id', 'unit_code')
        ->withPivot(
        'anggaran'
        );
    }
```

On table2 the column of unit_code is json

I try to use `Model::with(['workunit'])->get()` and get error:Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = json

Comment: and in what model have you added this function?